# geocodeAddressString: Save results in callback not working

Tags: objective-c, callback

I have a forward gecodoing method. I want to save the result from it in a variable so i can use it in the viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)getGeoInformations
{
    NSLog(@"Begin");
    __block NSString *returnAddress = @"";

    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"Isartor" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
            return;
        }
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[ @"FormattedAddressLines"];
        //addressString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
        NSString *str_latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", placemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
        NSString *str_longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", placemark.location.coordinate.longitude];
        returnAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@, %@, %@",
                        lines,
                        str_latitude, str_longitude];
        NSLog(returnAddress);
        NSLog(@"Ende");
        [self loadGeoInformations:returnAddress];
    }];
}
```

After www research, i know, that this is a asynchronous call and i have to use callback on this.

```
-(void)loadGeoInformations:(NSString*)returnAddress {

}
```

I have tried several things to store **returnAddress**, but with no success..

How can i save the results?

Thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an instance variable. At the top of your .m file declare the instance var NSString:

```
@interface YourFileHere {
    NSString *_returnAddress;
}
```

Then, later when you call the method that you pass the address into, you can save it to the instance variable to use later.

```
-(void)loadGeoInformations:(NSString*)returnAddress {
    _returnAddress = returnAddress;
}
```

Here is the full code with logs and comments showing how things will happen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // #1 - This is called first
    NSLog(@"Calling getGeoInformations in view did load.");
    [self getGeoInformations];
}

- (void)getGeoInformations {
    // #2 - This will be called during view did load.
    NSLog(@"Inside getGeoInformations");
    CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"Isartor" completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        // This is called later, at some point after view did load is called.
        NSLog(@"Inside completionHandler.");

        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
            return;
        }

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        NSArray *lines = placemark.addressDictionary[@"FormattedAddressLines"];
        NSString *str_latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", placemark.location.coordinate.latitude];
        NSString *str_longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%f", placemark.location.coordinate.longitude];
        NSString *returnAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@, %@, %@", lines, str_latitude, str_longitude];

        // #4 - Now we have the return address, so we can pass it to the load method.
        [self loadGeoInformations:returnAddress];
    }];

    // #3 - Anything here will be called during view did load, but BEFORE the completion handler of the geocoding process is called.
    NSLog(@"This is called third.");
}

- (void)loadGeoInformations:(NSString*)returnAddress {
    // #5 - this will be called last, some time after view did load is done.
    _returnAddress = returnAddress;
    NSLog(@"Inside load geo informations with return address: %@", _returnAddress);
}
```

Comment: Thank u Mike. I tried this.

In the Viewdidload i do:
[self getGeoInformations];
NSLog(_returnAddress);

But there is no output in the console..

Comment: Because it is asynchronous, the completion handler is called at a later time, most-likely some time after viewDidLoad is already done being called. I'll update my answer to show what you're going to want to do.

Comment: Ok, i understand in which sequence the code is been called.
I want to store _returnAddress in a parse table in another method
Sry, i dont figure out how i can use the text in _returnAddress? :(

Comment: When you nslog _returnAddress, like NSLog(@"%@", _returnAddress); what is the result?

Comment: NSLog in laodGeoInformations-----> (
    Istor,
    "43190 Tence",
    France
), 45.084247, 4.348809

Comment: OK, so it looks like that's working fine. Do you have any more questions?

Comment: Hmm.. the nslog of _returnAddress works only in loadGeoInformations.. But i want to use out it of this method.. Thats not working..

Comment: Where "outside" of the method? In another class? Somewhere else in this file?